# How to do my own custom runtime error class?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to do a simple custom runtime_error. I define the class:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>


namespace utils{

 class FileNotFoundException: public std::runtime_error{
  public:
   FileNotFoundException():runtime_error("File not found"){}
   FileNotFoundException(std::string msg):runtime_error(msg.c_str()){}
 };

};
```

Then I throw the error:

```
bool checkFileExistence( std::string fileName )
 {
  boost::filesystem::path full_path = boost::filesystem::system_complete(boost::filesystem::path(fileName));
  if (!boost::filesystem::exists(full_path))
  {
    char msg[500];
    _snprintf(msg,500,"File %s doesn't exist",fileName.c_str());
    throw new FileNotFoundException(msg);
  }
 }
```

And I use a try/catch block

```
    try{
          checkFileExistence(fileName);
     }
   catch(utils::FileNotFoundException& fnfe)
        {
          std::cout << fnfe.what() << std::endl;
     }
```

Runtime error is correctly thrown as FileNotFoundException but the line with std::cout is never reached and no line is writed to the console.

All ideas are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to use a default argument instead of overriding in your exception class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because you're throwing a pointer. Just do: `throw FileNotFoundException(msg);`.

Whenever you use a pointer, unless you're putting it into a container/wrapper you're probably not doing the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

You write `throw new FileNotFoundException(msg)`, it should be 'throw FileNotFoundException(msg)'. The rule is throw by value, catch by reference.

Comment: Unless you're Microsoft with MFC, then the rule is throw by pointer and catch by pointer. They created their exception classes before they had full support for standard throw/catch, which resulted in a few interesting compromises.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually throwing a pointer to a heap allocated object (FileNotFoundException*) so the types don't match.  Generally, throw by value and catch by reference ([rule 73](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm)).

Answer (score 1):

BTW, with the following declaration you create a copy of the msg string.

```
FileNotFoundException(std::string msg):runtime_error(msg.c_str()){}
```

Write "const std::string& msg" instead. It will put just a reference on a stack. While now you put the whole string on a stack.